# Artificial neural networks for Temperature prediction

Tags: python, computational-physics, machine-learning, neural-network

Imagine I want to consider the temperature for a process given several input varibales. The temperature can be anywhere between 400 and 500 K. Consider I have experimental data to train the network and then I want to predict the temperature for a test point.

As I understand the theory of NN activation function are needed to bound the value between 0 and 1. How could I proceed in my example? Should I just scale my data between 0 and 1? Are there good and bad methods to scale (of course there will be?). Or should I modify the activation function?

However, what if one of the training point's is at 600 K. If I bound the values it would be impossible for the NN to reach this value. I hope someone can give me clarity on this issues.

Best regards,

Gesetzt

Comment: For scaling your data, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70801/how-to-normalize-data-to-0-1-range. For questions involving data, machine-learning, and neural-networks, you would probably have better luck on the statistics stack exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NN activation functions don't need to be between 0 and 1. That's only done for classification problems. Many times you want them continuously differentiable and monotonic, though that isn't even required. RELU activation functions which are $\sigma(x)=max(0,x)$ are quite common for these kinds of scenarios.